# Eval multiple javascript variables not working

Tags: javascript, string, variables, eval

I am trying to grab some text content (HTML comments) on the page and convert it into variables. The text content will be of the format:

I have constructed some Javascript that works up to a point, but will not go past the final variable declaration "var shorturl = ..."

Javascript code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if (document.getElementById("ajax-gallery")) {
            var shortcode = '<!-- [var module="gallery"; var id="1"; var type="single"; var data="only";] -->';
            shortcode = shortcode.replace("<!-- [", "");
            shortcode = shortcode.replace("] -->", "");
            eval('shortcode');
            var shorturl = "shorturl = " + module + "/shortcode_" + type + ".php?id=" + id + "&data=" + data;
            eval('shorturl')
            updateGallery(shorturl, "ajax-gallery");
        }
      });
```

I would have thought this would work, but apparently not. I know that eval is frowned upon but at present I cannot find a "nicer" method.

Comment: `eval('shortcode');` does just that, eval's the string `shortcode` ... if you want to eval a variable, then pass a variable to eval ... e.g. `eval(shortcode);` - though, why are you evalling code in strings that you can just write? - your code is just https://jsfiddle.net/m93w721L/ no need for the evil eval ... edit: https://jsfiddle.net/m93w721L/1/ is actually all you need

Comment: @JaromandaX, I would assume OP is getting shortcode value from somewhere else. Just for the clarity its been hardcoded here. @WWD Can you control what gets stored in `shortcode`?

Comment: `I would assume` - @VivekAthalye yes, I didn't assume anything, and tried to help with the code provided (first part of comment should help regardless!! because it points out his error)

Comment: Assume that the var shortcode declaration doesn't exist, it's just there for demonstration of the requirement. The line below would exist in HTML and through a separate function be grabbed and then used as part of the above code:

Comment: `Assume that the var shortcode declaration doesn't exist` ... sure, so the first part of my first comment may help

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Jaromanda X, I assume you're meaning to remove the ' either side of shorturl and shortcode, i.e. 

eval(shortcode);
 eval(shorturl); // noted the missing ;

But I just get:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (garage-clear-out:231

Comment: @WWD Can you control what gets stored / passed in `shortcode`? If yes, there would be a better way and you can avoid `eval` altogether.

Comment: Thanks Chris85 - figured that now. Vivek I can't see a means for doing this with the setup as it is, save for just writing javascript direct into the TinyMCE editor (not ideal). In the end I have gone with a PHP approach to bypass this. It's just taken a bit more effort to amend the CMS to manage this but does the job.